# CUDA 2d array addressing within kernel

Tags: arrays, cuda

I have seen plenty of questions regarding it but none solved my problem.

I copy an initialized array of size n x n to global device memory as a 2D array, run some kernel and copy it back:

```
int image_width = 5;
int image_height = 4;
int n = image_height*image_width;
int *G = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int) * n*n);
size_t pitch;
int *dev_d = 0;

for (int x =0; x<n*n;x++) G[x] = 9;

cudaError_t cudaStatus = cudaMallocPitch(&dev_d, &pitch, n * sizeof(int), n);
cudaStatus  = cudaMemcpy2D(dev_d, pitch, G, n * sizeof(int), n * sizeof(int), n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); //A

setup_adjacency_matrix<<<4, 2>>>(n, dev_d, image_width,pitch);
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy2D(d, n * sizeof(int), dev_d, pitch, n * sizeof(int), n, CMCPYDTH); //copy back  //B
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaStatus);
```

For testing purposes I just want 4 blocks of 2 threads each. The test kernel itself also does not do anything particular:

```
__global__ void setup_adjacency_matrix(
    const unsigned int V,  int * const d,const unsigned int image_width,size_t pitch){
     d[blockIdx.x*V+threadIdx.x] = blockIdx.x*100+threadIdx.x; //problem here?
}
```

But the only threads from the first block seem to affect the array as the result is:

```
0 1 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

All works fine when i use th 1d array and do the copying in lines A and B like:

```
 cudaMemcpy(dev_d, G,  n * sizeof(int)* n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); //A
 cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(d,  dev_d, n * sizeof(int)* n, CMCPYDTH); //B
```

But i want to learn using the 2d arrays!
I am guessing the way I calculate the address of the array elements is wrong, and I also tried to multiply it by pitch like `d[blockIdx.x*V*pitch+threadIdx.x] = blockIdx.x*100+threadIdx.x;`, but did not manage to get a better result. What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

```
d[blockIdx.x*(pitch/sizeof(int))+threadIdx.x] = blockIdx.x*100+threadIdx.x;
```

this seems to work as intended... although i am not sure why... :)

Comment: That's because the rows in a CUDA array are have a distance of `pitch` bytes between them to satisfy the alignment rules of the GPU. Hence to advance the row of in your indexing you must add a offset of `pitch` bytes for each row, i.e. offset the index by `pitch` divided by the size of one array element, times the number of rows you want to skip.

Comment: As @datenwolf indicates, this is the expected type of indexing you will have to do when using `cudaMallocPitch` for allocations, and it is covered in the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g32bd7a39135594788a542ae72217775c)

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a mismatch between your data types in your arguments and what you are putting in.

Try this.

```
__global__ void setup_adjacency_matrix(
    const int V,  int *d,int image_width,size_t pitch){
     d[blockIdx.x*V+threadIdx.x] = blockIdx.x*100+threadIdx.x;
}
```

if it expects a different number type then it could cause an issue.

also it is usually good to make an input and an output array just in case you want to do more than one operation on the same initial data.

also you could make another memory allocation and output 
int IndexValue = blockIdx.x*V+threadIdx.x;
to find out if the index is logical.